# ¿Como sacar los registros que no cumplen con una condición where?

Tags: sql

Necesito un query donde se pueda filtrar todos los registros que no cumplan una condición `where` por ejemplo:

Tengo la tabla A y necesito mostrar los Numeros que no tengan letra A:

```
Numero|Letra|Descripción
00001 |  A  |AAAAAAAA
00002 |  Bv |AAAAAAAA
00003 |  A  |AAAAAAAA
00004 |  Ba |AAAAAAAA
00005 |  Bx |AAAAAAAA
00006 |  A  |AAAAAAAA
```

Y yo al correr:

```
select Numero
from A
where Letra = 'A'
```

El resultado sería:

```
Numero|
00001 |  
00003 | 
00006 |
```

Pero yo busco que el resultado sea al final:

```
Numero|
00002 |
00004 |
00005 |
```

Que son las que no cumplen con la condición del where.

Comment: Solamente pon un <>. Te dejo enlace a la documentación:

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/not-equal-to-transact-sql-exclamation?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Debes decir cuál es tu manejador de base de datos, porque a veces las consultas varían según el manejador, además, es posible que para este caso sea necesario refinar la consulta con respecto al `COLLATE`.

Answer (score 3):

Simplemente deberías cambiar el operador de igualdad `=` por el operador contrario que en este caso es `<>` y con eso debería buscarte aquellos elementos que no tengan el valor indicado, así:

```
select Numero
from A
where Letra <> 'A'
```

De modo que le pides a la consulta que saque todos los números que en la columna letra su valor es diferente de `A`

Answer (score 2):

Prefiero utilizar **NOT IN** porque cuando quieras negar más de un valor es más cómoda.

```
select Numero
from A
where Letra not in ('A')
```

Imaginemos que quieras tres letras:

```
select Numero
from A
where Letra not in ('A','B','C')
```

Answer (score 0):

Solo cambiando el `where Letra = 'A'` por `where Letra <> 'A'`

O igual puedes usar `where Letra != 'A'`

Ya que los operadores <> y != te dejaran solo lo que es diferente a "A"